# Asp.net Panel button click reloads panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel inside of the index2.aspx page. I want on button click(in panel) which adds values to DB to reload index2.aspx page as well and not just the panel page.

More info :
I have index2 shows dropdown of Sales Areas. 
The panel page A.k.a. budget.aspx allows adding more sales areas. 
So i want the dropdown on Index2.aspx to do a databind.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have tried researching. However I do not see a method call that will call and reload both index2.aspx and budget.aspx(panel). By default index2.aspx when reloaded goes to forecast.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to reload the page? That sounds as if you have some logic in `Page_Load` that gets executed `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`. Then put this logic into a separated method and call it from both places.

Otherwise you can also use `Response.Redirect("index2.aspx");` to reload it.

Comment: I have index2 shows dropdown of Sales Areas. The panel page A.k.a. budget.aspx allows adding more sales areas. So I want the dropdown to do a databind really.